# why we use setInt with select query instead of using getInt when value is already there in database

Tags: java, jdbc

why we use setInt with select query instead of using getInt when value is already there in database?

```
    try {
        conn = getConnection();


        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM circle where id =?");

        ps.setInt(1, circleId);

        Circle circle = null;
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            //String s = rs.getString(circleId);

            circle = new Circle(circleId, rs.getString("name"));

        }
```

Comment: You assign a value to the parameter of your query. So you "set" it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the value of the parameter to be used in the query. The `?` in the SQL represents the parameter, and here you're giving it a value.

When you call `getString()` later, that's getting a value from the *results* of the query, which are very different from the parameters sent as part of the query.

Parameterized SQL allows safe inclusion of values into queries, without needing to escape them to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), or worrying about data type conversions. You should read the [JDBC `PreparedStatement` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details.